# Adding custom properties to ASP.NET Identity with IdentityServer3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity-2, identityserver3

Using IdentityServer3 with ASP.NET Identity as an OAuth server, I can return roles and claims in the token response.  If I want to override IdentityUser and add LastName, how would I return that in the token response?  Or do I need to add LastName to AspNetUserClaims table instead of in the IdentityUser object/AspNetUsers table?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have to override GetClaimsForAuthenticateResult() in the UserService.  I tried adding a ClaimesIdentityFactory to the UserManager but it seems that doesn't actually get executed anymore.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1204